# effort needed for developing a website using Ruby; Mongodb; JSON. Assume very basic experience with web development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongodb

how much time would it take 4 beginners to develop a website (3-4 pages) using Ruby; Mongodb; JSON. Assume very basic experience with web development. Project has only 2-3 tables to be made. and focus is on providing a good user interface. business logic not complicated.

Comment: Could be 30 minutes. Could be 5 days or longer, depending on the design. Recommendation: break into small user stories and estimate each small piece, then add those estimates together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estimating time is one of a developer's most challenging tasks. No one is going to be able to tell you this, and if they do, it's likely BS.